# VS2019 Diagnostics Tools CPU usage stats shows too much of IO

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, diagnostics

I'm trying to figure out a way to profile some of my code with VS2019 pro diagnostics tools. After some unsuccessful attempts I created this code sample:

```cs
static void DoWork()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var vectors = Enumerable.Range(1, 50000)
        .Select(x => new Vector4(random.Next(10), random.Next(10), random.Next(10), random.Next(10)))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var v in vectors)
    {
        foreach (var v2 in vectors)
        {
            var v3 = Multiply(v, v2);
        }
    }
}

static Vector4 Multiply(Vector4 v1, Vector4 v2) 
{
    return v1 * v2;
}
```

So I put 2 breakpoints in the beginning and in the end of the method and start debugging it with CPU usage profiling on. After hitting the 2nd breakpoint CPU usage statistics on DoWork turn out to be really weird:
[image]

Really nothing useful. Even no call tree. And ridiculous amount of IO. I really don't get how I can make any use of it. Could anybody please help me out here? Am I doing something wrong? Is that a bug of VS?

Comment: I suggest that you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to get professional support.